# Ionic Components are displayed with black background color

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

(Ionic 5)
I'm not quite sure what's going on, I'm testing a test app compiled with --prod on a Samsung A50 (Android 11, security patch as of 12/01/2021), it works fine, and suddenly when I run it a day later , the ion-input, alert, etc. components appear with a black background, this happened at some point, the cell phone was not touched, it has the same mode as always, I recompiled the app, I don't know what happens.

Besides, another previously compiled app NOW has the same behavior, black component background.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem with my Xiaomi 10 where it seems to be on dark/night mode. What I did was remove/comment the .md body{} class on variables.scss under theme folder

and changed

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
```

into

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="only light" />
```

in public index.html